# How to /give tipped arrows in Windows-10 edition

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to make a feature in my survival minigame where every once and a while a random player is teleported to a hidden room via command blocks. Inside, players will be allowed to hit one button, then be teleported back to the main arena. Each button gives you different items, and one I want to have is to have it give you tipped arrows (like harming potion arrows). But, my command isn't working. Here is what I got:

```
/give @p arrow 1 0 {Potion:"harming"}
```

I found the last part [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/commands-command-blocks-and/2487839-get-stipped-arrows-potion-arrows). What is wrong with the command? As I said, I am on Windows-10 version (v1.1.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out!!!!
This is a command to give 1 arrow of leaping!!

```
/give @p arrow 1 10 = Arrow of Leaping
/give @p arrow 1 28 = Arrow of Poison
```

You could make these components on these 
 Example:
     /give @p potion 1 28 = Potion of Poison
And that's it

The last number determines what potion is applied to it.

Comment: Here's a link to a wiki page with the data values for all the arrows (under the "metadata" section): https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Arrow#:~:text=entity.arrow.name-,Metadata,-In%20Bedrock%20Edition    ...if that link stops working, I got to it by searching "minecraft arrow data values"

Answer (score 2):

```
/give @p minecraft:tipped_arrow 1 0 {Potion:"minecraft:harming"}
```

As shown in your link, the item name is `tipped_arrow`.

EDIT: Wait, just saw you were on Windows 10 edition. The Windows 10 `give` command doesn't support data tags, except (recently) for "can place on" and "can destroy". I don't know if there's another way to get what you want.

Answer (score -1):

To do a tipped arrow do:

/give arrow (desiredvalue) x

To find out x go to the creative mode menu and count starting from arrow of night vision (0:22) after finding the desired arrow ,add 5 on your desired arrow 
And that number will represent x

Comment: Wouldn't a list be more helpful? Instead of adding a step to ut?